# Compute numerical series using Fourier Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

My problem is to compute series $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac {1} {n^4} $ and $\sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac {1} {(2n+1) ^4} $ using Fourier Series for $ f(x) = \lvert x \rvert^3, \lvert x \rvert \leqslant 2 $.

I have found the Fourier Series for $ f(x) $ to be as follows:

$ f(x)=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {48[(n^2 \pi^2 - 2)\cos(n\pi) + 2]}{n^4\pi^4}\cos(\frac {n\pi}{2}x) $

In the picture below, $ f(x) $ and it's Fourier Series are plotted together.

[image: click here to see the image]

Any ideas of how to compute these two series?

---

P.S:

$ \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac {1}{(2n+1)^4} $ was obtained by dividing the mentioned Fourier Series into odd and even parts of n, considering $x=2$ and the result is:

$ \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac {1}{(2n+1)^4}=\frac {\pi^4}{96}-1 $

But still don't know how to compute $ \sum_{n=1} ^\infty \frac {1}{(n)^4} $.

Comment: Welcome. It's hard for me to debug your work, since I can't actually see what you did. I think extracting the desired series from your Fourier series is more tricky than you make it appear, so I suspect some error lies there. E.g. you must deal with $(-1)^n$ terms

Comment: @FShrike Thank you for your response.
I have calculated the Fourier coefficients, A0, An and Bn using online integral-calculators.
Then I just verified it using MATLAB (the picture attached to the post).
I also think there would be errs with my Fourier expression, but I don't know where.

Comment: Are you required to use $f(x)=|x|^3$? If not, the Fourier series trick is easier with $f(x)=x^4$. Otherwise, since you have already $\sum_n (2n+1)^{-4}$, note that $\sum_n n^{-4}=\sum_n (2n+1)^{-4}+2^{-4}\sum_n n^{-4}$ by splitting $\sum n^{-4}$ into even and odd sums

Comment: @sal Excuse me for my late reply and thank you for your response. About the problem, It was needed tu be computed by |x|^3.By the way, your answer to how to solve the problem is completely correct. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Saleh No problem, glad to help